# NSDataDetector and dates prior to the year 1900 brings back wrong date

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdatadetector

I posted this question on the Apple Dev forums https://devforums.apple.com/message/956514. I hope it's ok to post it here also. No response on the Apple dev forums yet.

Whenever I enter in a date that's less than the year 1900, NSDataDetector matches to the wrong date.

For example:

Jan 1, 1201 matches to Jan 1, 2015 and Feb 1, 1201 matches to Feb 1, 2014

It seems any date in January that's earlier than 1900 comes back with that date in January, but the year 2015. And any date later than January but with any year before 1900 matches to that date in the year 2014.

Here's my code for detecting the date:

```
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeDate error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:myDateString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [myDateString length])];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
     if (match.resultType == NSTextCheckingTypeDate) {
               determinedDate =  match.date;
     }
}
```

myDateString is just a string that contains the date value that needs to be parsed.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a known issue with NSDataDetector?

Answer (score 1):

Apple modified NSDataDetectors to work for dates from 1700 onwards.

A response to my bug report was the following:

> We lowered the limit but we will probably not lower it a lot more.
>
> The primary goal of DataDetectors is to handle dates in the close past
>   or future, dates that are more likely to be used for actual user
>   calendar events.
>
> Adding more years could lead to more false positives (with some phone
>   numbers formats for example) and historical dates are a minor use
>   case.
>
> We are leaving this report closed.

Seems like a reasonable response. So I'll just leave it at that for now. I think this works for me for now since I also provide users with a regular NSDataPicker control they can enter really old dates into.

Answer (score 0):

`NSDataDetector` works with regular expressions. Using regular expressions to parse dates is a bit limited. I guess that `NSDataDetector` is able to parse only `19xx` and `20xx` regular expressions for dates.

My advice - use `NSDateFormatter` instead.

Comment: It would be nice if you were able to modify this behaviour.

Comment: With an NSDateFormatter you can't type things like "lunch tomorrow" and you have to use a specific date format to enter the dates. It's not user friendly.